# Fitting the t distribution with 'fitdistr' in R

Tags: r, statistics

I have a set of data which are the percentages of claimed compensation being awarded to claimants in an earthquake, i.e. awarded values/claimed values. I want to model the distribution of these percentage values and used the `fitdistr` function in R to fit a t distribution with 1 degree of freedom.

The `fitdistr` returned `m` and `s` values as:

```
98.82907933(0.08574821)
```

and

```
2.87906212(0.10310584).
```

Now what is the formula for my distribution here? The function that allows me to calculate a percentage value when I input a value for claim compensation? Is it the pdf for the standard t distribution?

Comment: So `?fitdistr` tells me that `m` and `s` are the location and scale parameters respectively. So in this case you have a mean of 98.83 for awarded/claimed with a fitted standard error of 2.9. So what is it exactly what you want?

Comment: So if I have a claim value of, say 200,000, how do I use this distribution to calculate the corresponding percentage being awarded?

Comment: If you want to predict an outcome from another variable, you probably want a regression model of some type.

Comment: Could you tell me what it the function used for t distribution here?

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking the t distribution with 1 degree of freedom (AKA the Cauchy distribution) has no parameters that need to be fit. What fitdistr would be doing here is estimating the parameters of a location/scale transformation
t = (x - m)/s
in order that t best fits the t_1 distribution. Here x is the data.

Answer (score 1):

Since the t distribution with 1 df is also called the Cauchy distribution, you can model e.g. the probability of a claim being greater than 200,000 via:

```
params <- list(location=98.82907933,scale=2.87906212)
with(params,pcauchy(x=2e5,location,scale,lower.tail=FALSE)) ## 4.58e-6
```

Just to double-check, we can confirm that the location parameter is also the median:

```
with(params,pcauchy(x=location,location,scale,lower.tail=FALSE)) ## 0.5
```

You could also as suggested above transform your data and use `pt`:

```
with(params,pt((2e5-location)/scale,1,lower.tail=FALSE))  ## same as above
```

You can use `dt`/`dcauchy` for probability densities, `qt`/`qcauchy` for quantiles (the results of `qt` will have to be transformed as `z*scale+location`).